# Fix div relative positions after zoom

Tags: css, html

I have 3 div blocks, the first one is bigger on the left hand side of the web-page and the other are smaller in located the right hand side. I want their relative location become fixed in all browsers with any zoom level. The two div blocks in the right column drop down below the first big div if I zoom in now.

Here is [JFFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zahra/rFJR8/) link of the code, please zoom in/out to see the issue.

```
<div id="topdiv">

    <div class="bigdiv">
        <p> big div </p>
    </div>  

    <div id="staticcal">
        <p> staticcal </p>
    </div>      
    <div id="staticnews">
        <p> staticnews </p>
    </div>

</div
```

> 

```
#topdiv{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#b0c4de;
}

.bigdiv{
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 335px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #c7930d;
}

#staticcal {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 175px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #c7930d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
#staticnews {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 175px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #c7930d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `min-width: 800px;` to the `#topdiv` id in your CSS file.

CSS:

```
#topdiv {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using `border-radius` in your development, so I updated your file to account for cross browser use.  Here is an updated JSFiddle for your review.  Additionally I lined up your `staticcal and staticnews` by adding `float: left`.  Here is a minified version of your code:  [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rFJR8/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="topdiv">
    <div class="bigdiv">
        <p>big div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="staticcal">
        <p>staticcal</p>
    </div>
    <div id="staticnews">
        <p>staticnews</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topdiv {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    min-width: 800px;
}
.bigdiv, #staticcal, #staticnews {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #c7930D;
}
.bigdiv {
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 335px;
    height: 250px;
}
#staticcal, #staticnews {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 175px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; /*This will address iOS 1 to 3.X, Android 1.6-2.1, Safari 3 - 4*/
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; /*Firefox 1 to 3.6*/
    border-radius: 4px; /*IE 9+, Opera 10.5, Chrome, Safari 5, FireFox 4+, iOS 4, Android 2.1+,
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do know a list of css commands like this border-radius which are inconsistent cross browser ?

Comment: I updated the above file with the browser list for you.  Keep in mind that older browsers do not support this functionality.  You can substitute with jQuery, Javascript or use background images to achieve you goal.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. But I mean is there any thing else more than border-radius that I need to take care of in the future ?

Comment: From a cross browser utilization standpoint, no.  Being a news/media site, you will probably run into issues with page load latency.  A proactive approach would be to minify your CSS/JS files and optimize your images.  Google Developer has a great resource which will show where you need to improve:  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/.